# How to cut the same geometry into two similar meshes?

Tags: mesh, knife-tool

I am modelling an airplane, and I want to cut windows into both it's front doors. Every door is a separate object.

What I tried:

1. I selected both doors in Object mode
2. I went into Edit mode
3. I pressed `k` to activate the Knife tool, then `z` to enable cut-through.
4. I cut the window into the left door.

The result was that I had the window only in one of the doors, but I wanted it to be in both doors. The doors are exactly mirrored along the X axis.

How can I make the Knife cut two meshes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cut through with the knife, press <kbd>Z</kbd> after you've pressed <kbd>K</kbd>. It won't work if you've selected 2 objects though. You could also use the *Knife Project* tool for the same kind of purpose, it would allow you to cut with a circle or with the shape you want. You could also link-duplicate your object and mirror it, so that every change you'll make on an instance will also happen on another one.

Comment: As I said in my question, pressing `z` did ___not___ help. I ended up deleting one of the doors, cutting the window into the left one, then `Duplicate linked`ing and mirroring the duplicate.

Comment: oh ok you say "every door is a separate object", it explains why "cut through" doesn't work, you can't cut through if the other mesh is another object.

Comment: Also not if I selected both in Object mode, then went into Edit mode ? I can do everything else on both meshes, so why not Knife cut through ?

Comment: yes I guess knife doesn't work this way yet, it may comes later

Answer (score 1):

I would only cut one door and then use symmetries to create the other door or use a mirror modifier.